# CartThrobTax being added when disabled

Tags: cartthrob, shopping-cart

For some reason I cannot disable the tax on certain products.  I have the no_tax set to YES in my product channel but it is still being added.

I am running EE 2.7.0 and Cart Throb 2.4

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" limit="1" status="not closed" dynamic="yes"}

                        <h1>{title}</h1>

                        <p>{product_description}</p>
                        {if product_original_price && product_original_price > product_price}
                            <p>Regular Price: {product_original_price}<br />
                                <span class="sale_price">Sale Price: {product_price}</span> </p>
                        {if:else}
                            <p>Regular Price: {product_price}</p>
                        {/if}
                            {if no_tax !="Yes"}<p>Price including tax {product_price:plus_tax}</p>{/if}

                        {exp:cartthrob:add_to_cart_form 
                            entry_id="{entry_id}"
                            no_tax="{no_tax}"
                            no_shipping="{no_shipping}"
                            return="shop/view_cart"} 
                            <p>
                                {exp:cartthrob:item_options entry_id="{entry_id}"}
                                    {if dynamic}
                                        <label>{option_label}</label>
                                        {input}
                                    {if:else}
                                        {if options_exist}
                                            <label>{option_label}</label>
                                            {select} 
                                                <option {selected} value="{option_value}">
                                                    {option_name}{if option_price_numeric > 0} +{option_price}{/if}
                                                </option>
                                            {/select}
                                        {/if}
                                    {/if}
                                {/exp:cartthrob:item_options}

                            </p>
                            <p>
                            {if "{inventory}" == "0" }
                                <strong>This item is out of stock</strong>
                            {if:else}
                                <label for="product_quantity">Quantity</label>
                                <input type="text" id="product_quantity" name="quantity" size="8"  />
                            {/if}
                            </p>
                            <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart" />

                        {/exp:cartthrob:add_to_cart_form}


            {/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had TAX on shipping checked off!!